# Reading a CSS file removes the last character?

Tags: c#, css

i have a scenario where i have to show the css file to the user in the front end 
for that i am reading the css file where a last character is being replaced, can any one help me out here dont know where am i going wrong.

this is code am using

```
        string mts = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/css/store.css");
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
            MatchCollection mt = Regex.Matches(text, @"[^}]?([^{]*{[^}]*})", RegexOptions.Multiline);                
            if (mt.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < mt.Count; i++)
                {
                    mts = mts + mt[i].Captures[0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return Json(mts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The above code outputs the result wrong,

```
     Css file content

        .h1{

        }
        @media-screen{
             .test{    
                 }
        }

    result using the above code

        .h1{

        }
        @media-screen{
             .test{    
        }
```

can any one help me here

Comment: What happens if you loop through all the captures instead of just taking the first one?

Comment: @dbugger am missing that brace in mt itself

Answer (score 0):

Testing your regex on this page http://rubular.com/ shows that it isn't matching the final curly brace (like you observed in your execution).

Would something like this work?

```
[^{}]+{(.|\n)+}
```

Comment: what happens if there are multiple nesteds

Comment: It would leave off the last curly brace in your match

Comment: this is failing in this case h{
 
 dfdfdfdf

}

@media-screen
{
 
 .test{
  
  
  }



.test1{

}
}

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this is the case where it would leave out the last curly brace again. How many nested selectors are you looking to match? Infinite?

Comment: dont know thats a css file

Comment: That's good to hear. If that answers your question, could you please mark my answer as accepted?